# Change style of div with specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I am truely sorry if this is a repeated question.

I want to set max-height of #menudd.show to satify my transition. I want to do this in javascript so i can specify the value more precisely.

This is what i got and its not working for some reason...

HTML:

```
<div id="menudd">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="shotterm.html">Short-Term</a>
    <a href="middleterm.html">Middle-Term</a>
    <a href="longterm.html">Long-Term</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menudd {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px 15px black;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#menudd.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#menudd." + show).get(0).style.maxHeight = document.getElementById("menudd").getElementsByTagName("A")[0].offsetHeight * document.getElementById("menudd").getElementsByTagName("A").length + "px";
```

This outputs "show is not defined" in the console.

If i use $("#menudd.show").get(0).style.maxHeight it outputs "cannot read property 'style' of undefined" in the console.

If i use $("#menudd.show").style.maxHeight it outputs "cannot read property 'maxHeight' of undefined" in the console.

Any help is highly appreciated! Good day to you. :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: `$("#menudd." + show)`  should that not be just `$("#menudd.show")`?  I don't understand the variable usage.

Comment: What is the console output? if any, please add it to the question.

Comment: I have added this to the post now.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you said you wanted to look for an element with class "show" inside a div.

You are currently looking for a variable, and not a class. Change this:

```
$("#menudd." + show)
```

To this:

```
$("#menudd.show")
```

To set the max height, change it to this:

```
$( "#menuadd.show" ).css( { "maxHeight": document.getElementById("menudd").getElementsByTagName("A")[0].offsetHeight * document.getElementById("menudd").getElementsByTagName("A").length + "px" } );
```

Comment: I may have expressed myself poorly. I want to set max-height of #menudd.show to satisfy my transition. I want to do this, so when i add more <a> tags to the dropdown, it will change the max-height automatically. That's why i want to do it in JS

Comment: I fixed the issue you were having, which was "This outputs "show is not defined" in the console."

Comment: I'm sorry, but this didnt fix the problem. I added a new outputed error.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This does not seem to set the max-height. I tried ".css({ "maxHeight": "100px"});", ".css({"max-height": "100px"});", ".css("maxHeight", "100px");", ".css("max-height", "100px");". These all have the correct quotation, and none of 'em changed anything. Is there maybe a way of doing this with pure JS, no JQuery? The only thing i dont know how to do in pure JS, is to set max-height of object #menudd.show, cause its neither an id nor a class, its both.

Comment: I don't know. Please open a separate question for that and accept my answer as I solved the issue you posted about. I will be happy to look at your new question once you post it.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, I will add some stuff for readability - like a `padding: 0.5em;` into you dropdown menu. Also, the `<br />` tag after the `</a>` tags (excluding the last one).

**Second**, the errors happened because there are no element in the page with the class `show`. I added it to the `<div>` of the dropdown to show it working and make the errors go away.

*Remember this*: if the console says there it is `undefined`, chances are that either you messed up in how to select the element **OR** it seriously doesn't exists because you misspelled a letter or let's say you forgot to add a class to a given tag (like in this case).

**Third**, your code in working condition is available below. It isn't using jQuery easing stuff but pure JavaScript - except by the `onclick` event that is better to use with jQuery:

```js
$("#menu-dropdown").on("click", function() { 
 
  var menu_dropdown = document.getElementById("menudd");
 var menu_item = menu_dropdown.getElementsByTagName("A");
 
  $("#menudd").toggleClass("show");

 menu_dropdown.style.maxHeight = menu_item[0].offsetHeight * menu_item.length + "px";
  
  } );
```

```css
#menudd {
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px 15px black;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#menudd.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="menu-dropdown">DropDown</span>
<div id="menudd">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a><br />
  <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a><br />
  <a href="shotterm.html">Short-Term</a><br />
  <a href="middleterm.html">Middle-Term</a><br />
  <a href="longterm.html">Long-Term</a><br />
</div>
```

You can view it working also on [this video](https://youtu.be/iphowcIYqIM) (Youtube) that I recorded.

**Fourth**, you can add classes, in pure JavaScript, easily. I won't write about it in full since there is a famous question with a godly answer by [Peter Boughton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9360/peter-boughton) already on Stack Overflow. Read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/1494516).

Anyway, to add a class, simply call:

```
document.getElementById("MyElementID").className += " MyClass";
```

It is important to note the *space*. Since it is a string with values, you need to put it otherwise it will treat all the classes as one word (one class) that doesn't exists.

To remove:

```
document.getElementById("MyElementID").className = document.getElementById("MyElementID").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/g , '' );
```

Explanation available through Peter's answer. So read it there (important)!

**Finally**, this is out of the scope of the question and merely a reminder: I need to state that if this is a dropdown menu, you will need to add the `show` class after some focus (or click even) by calling a function in a master menu of some sort and not by hardcoding it into the `<div>` like I did to show the code working. For example, a "*Cars Brand*" item of a menu would have a dropdown with the available car brands (*Ford*, *Toyota* and etc) after focusing on it.

So, it is wise to transform it in a function that receives the ID of the target dropdown to open. And do not forget to close it after losing focus (or whatever).

Comment: I have a button set up, and it works 100% fine. The reason i dont have class "show" on the div, is because i am toggeling it with this

`$("#menubtn").on("click", function() {
 $("#menudd").toggleClass("show");
});`

When i do what you suggested, I just set the max-height of the div when its even not visible, meaning the transition wont work

Comment: @LukasKnudsen is this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iphowcIYqIM) the behavior you are expecting? If yes, look at the code again. I edited it. If not, I suggest being more clearer because technically, this all responds your question. So I'm not sure many people are following what is exactly the problem with your code or what you are trying to achieve. Like, show a foreign example of what you want and one of what you have (photos helps in these cases).

Comment: Your answer was perfectly correct. Your answer helped me. I got the final information on this artical: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232737/jquery-css-not-working/47232819#47232819