# jQuery - .css() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Exclaimer, this is mostly snippet code, cause I didn't know how else to explain this. Please don't hate :3

The jQuery code is supposed to set the "max-height" property for "#dd.show". So can someone tell me why this doesn't work:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $("#dd").toggleClass("show");
});

var dv = document.getElementById("dd");
var item = dv.getElementsByTagName("A");
$("#dd.show").css("max-height", item[0].offsetHeight * item.length + "px");
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

#btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 52.5px;
}

#dd {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#dd.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

#dd.show:hover {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#dd a {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#dd a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">press me</button>
<div id="dd">
  <a href="#">press me 1</a>
  <a href="#">press me 2</a>
  <a href="#">press me 3</a>
  <a href="#">press me 4</a>
</div>
```

This is how it's supposed to look like. The only thing i changed was removing the .css JQuery and added "max-height" manually:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $("#dd").toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

#btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 52.5px;
}

#dd {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#dd.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 225px;
}

#dd.show:hover {
  border-radius: 37.5px;
}

#dd a {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#dd a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">press me</button>
<div id="dd">
  <a href="#">press me 1</a>
  <a href="#">press me 2</a>
  <a href="#">press me 3</a>
  <a href="#">press me 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging work (like adding `console.log()` calls) to see what `item[0].offsetHeight` and `item.length` are? The element does get a `max-height` value set. Also using a mix of jQuery and DOM APIs is kind-of confusing and error-prone.

Comment: You are dynamically adding the "show" class when the button is clicked. But you are trying to add styling to the "show" class at some other point (and at that point the "show" class doesn't exist). Change/add the css within the click event.

Comment: The thing is, even if i write "100px" instead of "item[0].offsetHeight * item.length + 'px' ", it still gives the same result. No max-height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery works fine, you problem lies here: `$("#dd.show")`. At the point where you execute that code the selector `#dd.show` won't find anything as there exists no element like that. (You only add the `show` class on button click)

You will have to add that css when pressing the button. Also note that `$.css` adds in-line css. (like `<div style="max-height:100px;"></div>`)

Answer (score 0):

at the time that this line executes:

```
$("#dd.show").css("max-height", item[0].offsetHeight * item.length + "px")
```

you don't know for a fact that the `div` with id `dd` also has the `show` class. Since the `show` class is dynamically toggled, I'm guessing that this element

```
<div id="dd">...</div>
```

doesn't have the show class when your jquery code is running. That means that `$("#dd.show")` isn't returning anything which explains why your css method isn't working.

This is precisely the kind of thing that you should use plain css for if possible. If you can get the behavior you want by simply specifying

```
#dd.show {
    max-height: 225px;
}
```

then I'd just do that.

If you want to test this to see if I'm right, then add the following line right before you try to set the max-height property with jQuery.

```
console.log($("#dd").hasClass('show'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the sliding problem. I added an IF statement to check if the "show" class is active. If it is then toggle it and set "max-height" to 0px. If no, then toggle it and set "max-height" to the other long value :) Thanks for all the help guys. You helped me towards the finishline :3

Here is the final code for people that might come in later to see the solution :3

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
 if(!$("#dd").hasClass("show")) {
 $("#dd").toggleClass("show");

 $("#dd.show").css("max-height", document.getElementById("dd").getElementsByTagName("A")[0].offsetHeight * document.getElementById("dd").getElementsByTagName("A").length + "px");
} else {
 $("#dd").toggleClass("show");

 $("#dd").css("max-height", "0px");
}
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

#btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 52.5px;
}

#dd {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#dd.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

#dd.show:hover {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#dd a {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#dd a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">press me</button>
<div id="dd">
  <a href="#">press me 1</a>
  <a href="#">press me 2</a>
  <a href="#">press me 3</a>
  <a href="#">press me 4</a>
</div>
```